# Webpack error: Module has no exported member 'Rgb'

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, webpack, c3.js

While compiling the app, im receiving following errors in the console:

```
[default] C:\app\node_modules\@types\c3\index.d.ts:28:41
Generic type 'Selection<GElement, Datum, PElement, PDatum>' requires 4 type argument(s).
[default] C:\node_modules\@types\c3\index.d.ts:351:56

Module '"C:\node_modules/@types/d3/index"' has no
exported member 'Rgb'.
[default] C:\node_modules\@types\c3\index.d.ts:355:47

Module '"C:/node_modules/@types/d3/index"' has no
exported member 'Rgb'.
[default] C:\node_modules\@types\c3\index.d.ts:833:51

Module '"C:/node_modules/@types/d3/index"' has no
exported member 'Rgb'.
[default] C:\node_modules\@types\c3\index.d.ts:943:58

Module '"C:/node_modules/@types/d3/index"' has no
exported member 'Rgb'.
[default] Checking finished with 5 errors
```

Im using c3.js and d3.js libraries.

Any help appreciated.

**edit**: errors while typing `npm install types/d3 --save-dev` into cmd.

[image]

Comment: are you using typescript?

Comment: @SurajRao Yeah.

Comment: npm install --save-dev @types/d3  didnt work?

Comment: @SurajRao After typing that command into my cmd, few errors appears, I will drop image into my post in a sec.

Comment: looks like it cannot find git. Have you installed git in the system?

Comment: once done. do npm cache clean and then the same command

Comment: @SurajRao I had git installed. Npm cache clean helped. But the errors are still there tho

Comment: git --version works? If it doesnt check your system path variable

Comment: @SurajRao Yeah, git works. I've installed the @types/d3. But the problem is still there. Unfortunately.

Comment: If anybody is interested, ive dealt with it. I just deleted all c3 and d3 folders/files from `node_modules` folder. And just imported c3 and d3 as stand-alone files (c3.js and d3.js). Also Ive not imported any modules, just declared c3 as variable in component.ts file. `declare var c3:any;`.

Comment: @H.Doe thanks for coming back to share your solution. Perhaps make it the actual answer, for others to easily see.

Comment: @teachtyler I will post full answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found the root cause. 
It's caused by difference in D3 version used by C3 and the newest version of D3 available on npm.

If you install newest version of C3 `npm install c3 --save` `npm install types/c3 --save-dev` you'll see versions like here (I had this two in my package json and installed them with `npm install`: 
[image]

If you also install d3 and it's typings it will install version 4.4.1 or higher and 4.4.1 types are not compatible with c3 typings.

**SOLUTION:**

1. Remove from your `package.json` d3 and types/d3.
2. Remove d3 and types/d3 from node_modules
3. Optionally remove also c3 and types/c3 from node_modules
4. Run `npm install`.

At this point you shuold be good. C3 will use d3 in the right version and there will be no errors about wrong generic type or not exported member Rgb.